# How can I form a `final` reference to a non-final class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, final

`final` is an excellent keyword. It lets me prevent inheritance from a class. It also lets the compiler skip the runtime dispatch mechanisms when calling virtual functions or accessing virtual bases.

Suppose now that I have some non-`final` class `T` with virtual functions and/or base classes. Suppose also that I have a reference to an instance of this class. **How could I tell the compiler that this particular reference is to the fully-derived complete object, and not to a base sub-object of a more derived type?**

My motivations are classes like `optional` and `vector`. If I invoke `optional<T>::operator*()`, I get a `T&`. However, I know with certainty that this reference really is a `T`, not some more derived object. The same applies to `vector<T>` and all the ways I have of accessing its elements.

I think it would be a great optimization to skip the dynamic dispatch in such cases, especially in debug mode and on compilers not smart enough to look through the `optional` and `vector` implementations and devirtualize the calls.

Comment: "Great optimizations" like this typically come with not-so-great price of making code less readable and no actual difference in execution time.

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but `final` (as well as `override`) aren't really *keywords*. They are special identifiers that are recognized in certain contexts only. It's perfectly valid to have a function named `final`. If it's a member function you could even mark it as `final` like `void final() final;` :)

Comment: You can even contrive a scenario where `final final() final;` is valid.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to mark your `T` class `final`. Why wouldn't you do that? You get the certainty that a `T&` is really a reference to a concrete `T` enforced by the compiler. Doing it any other way is just asking for trouble when someone subclasses your `T` and your "certainty" goes out the window.

Not to mention that compilers can be smarter than you think in terms of identifying the concrete type of a reference and skipping virtual despatch...

Comment: Are you talking about all code in a single translation unit? Or is the implementation of the function taking a reference in a different translation unit than the optional?

Comment: I actually think your compiler should be able to know that you are using T and not a derived as it stores T by value. My guess is that the optimizer doesn't propagates it along to any relevant positions. Might be worth a bug report if you can reproduce on a small example?

Answer (score 2):

Formally, you can do this:

```
void final(A &a) {
  static_cast<A*>(dynamic_cast<void*>(&a))->foo();
}
```

`dynamic_cast<void*>` returns a pointer to the most-derived type (and `static_cast` *from* `void*` cannot select a polymorphic base class), so the compiler can know that `A::foo` is being called.  However, compilers don’t seem to take advantage of this information; they even generate the obvious *extra* instructions to actually perform the dynamic cast (even though it’ll of course be undefined behavior if it fails).

You can, certainly, devirtualize yourself by actually writing `a.A::foo()` whenever verbosity and genericity permit.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I wasn’t relying on “completely-defined”, but on the similarity provision; nonetheless, you are correct because of the possibility of **multiple**, overlapping (notional) `T[1]` objects.  Clang and GCC do nothing even with `&a+2` (which would itself be undefined behavior in the absence of a real backing array!).  Meanwhile, I’ll use just the `dynamic_cast` trick.

Comment: `struct Ancestor : A {}; struct Derived : Ancestor, A {}; Derived d; final(d);` This is all completely defined, yet the dynamic/static casts produce a different `A&` than was passed in.

Comment: @Filipp: I think you have a point about the optimization, but that exact case is ambiguous.